# How can I remove elements from a list that don't fit between a specified range?

Tags: python, list

I'm working on a project for school where I need to remove any elements from a list (data) that don't fit between a lower and upper range given by the user. We are supposed to use a loop with an if statement inside.

This is what my code looks like so far:

```
lower = int(input("Lower bound: "))
upper = int(input("Upper bound: "))
    
j = 0
while j < len(data):
    if data[j] < lower or data[j] > upper:
        data.pop(j)
    j += 1
for i in range(len(data)):
    print(data[i], end = " ")
print()
```

I thought I had it right before I realized that there were still a few numbers that are outside of the parameters.

This is what data contained at this point in my code right before I prompted for lower and upper:
`1 10 10 11 14 20 20 24 25 25 32 33 34 36 41 42 44 45 45 48`

and this is what it contained after entering 11 for lower and 41 for upper:
`10 11 14 20 20 24 25 25 32 33 34 36 41 44 45`

Every item that should be included (11-41) is included, but it also includes 3 numbers outside of the range.

I apologize if the formatting for my post is incorrect, this is my first time using stack overflow. Thank you in advance

Comment: If you e. g. `pop` the list item at index 1, the item at index 2 becomes the item at 1 and must be checked if it is in range.

Comment: List comprehensions are also an excellent way to solve your problem with much less code and simplicity: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: @MichaelButscher is right. While you removing the value the index is shifted. Just add `j -= 1` after `data.pop(j)` and your program should work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange result when removing item from a list while iterating over it in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

As it has been answered already, the problem is that when you pop element of the list, indexes shifts to the left and you omit the next item.

You can simply modify your code and increment your index "j" only if you don't pop any element in current iteration.

```
lower = int(input("Lower bound: "))
upper = int(input("Upper bound: "))

j = 0
while j < len(data):
    if data[j] < lower or data[j] > upper:
        data.pop(j)
    else:
        j += 1
for i in range(len(data)):
    print(data[i], end = " ")
print()
```

Answer (score 2):

Never modify lists while you're enumerating them.

A list comprehension is ideal for this.

```
lower = 11
upper = 41

data = [1, 10, 10, 11, 14, 20, 20, 24, 25, 25, 32, 33, 34, 36, 41, 42, 44, 45, 45, 48]
data = [x for x in data if lower <= x <= upper]

print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
[11, 14, 20, 20, 24, 25, 25, 32, 33, 34, 36, 41]
```

Answer (score 0):

As the first comment suggests, it is because you are popping items from the list while iterating through it using indices. More precisely, when you pop `1` at index `0` in the first iteration, the `10` at index `1` gets the index `0`. Then, in your next iteration you continue with `j = 1`, thus the `10` now at index `0` never gets checked against the criterium. It is more error-proof to append the needed elements to a new list:

```py
lower = int(input("Lower bound: "))
upper = int(input("Upper bound: "))
    
data = [1, 10, 10, 11, 14, 20, 20, 24, 25, 25, 32, 33, 34, 36, 41, 42, 44, 45, 45, 48]
data_in_range = []

j = 0
while j < len(data):
    if data[j] >= lower and data[j] <= upper:
        data_in_range.append(data[j])
    j += 1
for i in range(len(data_in_range)):
    print(data_in_range[i], end = " ")
print()
```